On-demand loading in combination with modified SQL in information link
I am fetching data from an oracle database using an information link, and in the select statement of that information link, I am modifying a column doing this:
CASE WHEN R1."CORPORATE_ID" = '0.0.0001.1' THEN  SUBSTR(R4."STRING_VALUE", 1, INSTR(R4."STRING_VALUE", ' ') - 1) ELSE R1."CORPORATE_ID" END AS "CORPORATE_ID"
However, when I then use the CORPORATE_ID in my on-demand loading, it seems to refer to the original R1."CORPORATE_ID", not the one I create in my select statement in sql.
Is there any way to have the on-demand loading occur based on the column I composed?

You need to create a new CORPORATE_ID column element in the information designer which includes the logic you outlined. It can then be used to filter on demand tables.
